# How to add an in command to a where clause in LINQ?

Tags: linq

If I have a where clause as follows:

```
Where item.field == "value"
```

How can I change the statement in LINQ to be:

```
   Where item.field in ("value1","value2","value3")
```

Seems simple, not working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare your "in" values collection in a variable first:

```
var collection = new[] { "value1","value2","value3" };
```

And then use it in query:

```
...
where collection.Contains(item.field)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Or in lambda syntax(say you have a collection you are searching through):

```
var lookup = new[] { "value1","value2","value3" };
var result = collection.Where(x=> lookup.Contains(x)).ToArray();
```